# Submultiplicative seminorms in the algebra of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

¿Are there any submultiplicative seminorms in the algebra of real or complex random variables?
I've tried with the seminorms of the form: $$ p(X)=\sup\{\;|E[XY]| \mid E[Y] \leq 1 \;\} $$
For a $ E[\,\cdot\,]$ expectation function (suppose we have multiple probability measures and then multiple expectation functions).

But I think that seminorms aren't finite...

Motivation: I want to find a topology and more structure that allows me to define continuity and differentiation of functions of random variables or mixed functions of random variables and $ R^n $. I'm trying to find some natural "results" as:
$F:\mathbb R \longrightarrow R$ and $V$ is continous at $t_0$ if $ \forall w \in \Omega $ $ \lim_{t \to t_0 } F(t,w)=F(t_0,w) $. Or $F$ is differentiable if $\exists L: \mathbb R \longrightarrow R$ and $V$ linear function that $ \forall w \in \Omega $ $$ \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{F(t_0+h,w)-F(t_0,w)-L(h,w)}{h}=0 $$

I thought that I could do so with multiple seminorms that if $p(v)=0 $ forall seminorm $p$, then $ v=0 $.

Thanks